# How to access a `<div>` tag inside a `<p>` tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$("p div").click(function() {
  $(this).css({
    "color": "#F00",
    "font": "bold 20px verdana",
    "background-color": "#0FF"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Hello<div> World!</div></p>
```

Nothing happens when I click the “World” text, and when I inspect the elements, it says:

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<div> World</div>
<p></p>
```

Notice those `<p>` tags. How could that happen?

Comment: I think a span would be more appropriate to put inside of a <p> tag. It would also be easier if you give your element an id, than way you can use the id in the jquery selector `$("#myitem").css...` if you need to select several, you could use the jQuery class selector.

Comment: I tried <span> inside <p> and gave the same result

Comment: <span> by itself isn't the total solution but a <span> tag is allowed inside of a <p> where a <div> isn't. I'd still opt to use the id or class selector if you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser is kicking the `<div>` out of the `<p>` because it isn't a valid placement, so you won't be able to select it there.

Browsers often do try to make corrections for invalid HTML, but the result isn't necessarily predictable, so you'll need to use valid HTML instead.

---

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1

> *"The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself)."*

Comment: @ghjkl: It shouldn't. [Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/wE3wj/) Which browser are you testing with?

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting.  The problem is that your browser is working correctly, and I hate when that happens.  `P` is an in-line tag and `DIV` is a block tag (that is, it represents a *rectangular* area of the screen, as opposed to a possibly-irregular section of text like a in-line tag could) and there's a rule that you cannot put a block tag *inside* an in-line tag, so that's how your browser solved it.

**EDIT:**  I notice @magicmike suggested a good solution:

```
<p>Hello<span> World!</span></p>
```

Comment: `P` is also block level. Note that this doesn't change whether it's valid to have a `DIV` inside of a `P`, but your reasoning for why is inaccurate.

Comment: @JAAulde -- eek, so it is.  Now I don't have a good explanation *why* a DIV is forbidden within a P.  All I can tell the OP is, the W3C gods have spoken.  Deal with it.  (Does anyone else have a good explanation, or any explanation, for the no-DIV-inside-P rule?)

Answer (score 0):

The browser will not respect your placement of a `div` inside a `p`. Change it to a `span`. Here's [a working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BhHDw/3/).

Answer (score 0):

It is not valid for a `div` to appear within a `p`. That's why Firefox has re-arranged your [broken] HTML, and you can see its "fixed" result through Firebug. **Use a `span` instead.**

Also, don't forget to put this event handler setup inside an onLoad handler, because your `p` and `span` don't necessarily exist when your script initially runs:

```
$(function() {
    $('p span').click(function(){
        $(this).css({
            'color':            '#F00',
            'font':             'bold 20px verdana',
            'background-color': '#0FF'
        });
    });
});
```

[Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/FZ4LB/)

Comment: @ghjkl: The fiddle _demonstrates_ that this works. Did you forget to use the `$(function() {});` on-load wrapping?